# How do I create a configurable product programmatically and assign simple products?

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to create some simple products, then have those simple products assigned to a configurable product programmatically. But no matter what I try, it seems to not associate them. What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I have so far. I have commented out all the attempts I have tried too so you can see what I've tried already:

```
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Get;

use Magento;
use Company\Module\Helper\Helper;

class OutboundItem extends Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $indexerFactory;
    public $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
        Helper $helper
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getId();

        // Get the the list of products that need importing from the document.
        $items = $this->helper->getItems();

        // Loop through all the results.
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                // Create common product info variables.
                $product_name = $item->ProdName;
                $price = $item->UnitPrice;
                $weight = $item->NetWeight;
                $categoryIds = [2, $this->helper->getCategoryIdByName(substr($product_name, 0, 1))];

                // Create variable to store the created variant ids.
                $variant_ids = array();

//                $prodData = array();
                // Loop through the variants.
                foreach ($item->variants as $variant) {
                    $product = $this->productFactory->create();

                    // Preparing data for new customer.
                    $product->setSku($product_name . '_' . $variant->Code);
                    $product->setName($variant->Description); // Name of Product
                    $product->setAttributeSetId($product->getDefaultAttributeSetId()); // Attribute set id
                    $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
                    $product->setWeight($weight); // weight of product
                    $product->setVisibility(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
                    $product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
                    $product->setPrice($variant->SalesPrice); // price of product
                    $product->setStockData(
                        array(
                            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                            'manage_stock' => 1,
                            'is_in_stock' => 1,
                            'qty' => $variant->AvailableQuantity
                        )
                    );

                    $product->setWebsiteIds(array($websiteId));
                    $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
                    $product->setStoreId($storeId);

                    $colour = $variant->value2;
                    $colourId = $this->helper->createOrGetId('color', $colour);
                    $product->setColor($colourId);

                    $size = $variant->value1;
                    $sizeId = $this->helper->createOrGetId('size', $size);
                    $product->setSize($sizeId);

                    // Save data.
                    $product->save();

                    if ($product->getId() > 0) {
                        $variant_ids[] = $product->getId();
//                        $prodData[$product->getId()] = array(
//                            '0' => array(
//                                'label' => 'Size',
//                                'attribute_id' => $this->helper->getAttribute('size')->getAttributeId(),
//                                'value_index' => $sizeId
//                            ),
//                            '1' => array(
//                                'label' => 'Color',
//                                'attribute_id' => $this->helper->getAttribute('color')->getAttributeId(),
//                                'value_index' => $colourId
//                            )
//                        );
                    }

                    $prodConfAttr = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
                    $prodConfAttr->setConfigurableProductLinks($variant_ids);
                    $product->setExtensionAttributes($prodConfAttr);
                }

                // Instantiate magento customer object.
                $product = $this->productFactory->create();

                // Preparing data for new customer.
                $product->setTypeId('configurable'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
                $product->setSku($product_name);
                $product->setName($product_name); // Name of Product
                $product->setAttributeSetId($product->getDefaultAttributeSetId()); // Attribute set id
                $product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
                $product->setWeight($weight); // weight of product
                $product->setVisibility(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
                $product->setPrice($price); // price of product
                $product->setStockData(
                    array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 1,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1
                    )
                );
                //setCategoryId?
                $product->setWebsiteIds(array($websiteId));
                $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
                $product->setStoreId($storeId);

                // Set variants
//                $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId($product->getDefaultAttributeSetId());
//                $product->setAssociatedProductIds($variant_ids);
//                $product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
//
//                $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(
//                    $this->helper->getAttribute('color')->getAttributeId(),
//                    $this->helper->getAttribute('size')->getAttributeId()
//                ), $product);
//                $attData = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
//                $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
//                $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($attData, $product);
////                $prodData = array();
////                foreach($variant_ids as $key => $id) {
////                    $prodData[$id] = array(
////                        '0' => array(
////                            'label'
////                        )
////                    );
////                }
//                $product->setConfigurableProductsData($prodData);

//                unset($variant_ids);

                // Save data.
                $product->save();

                echo $this->helper->getPrint($variant_ids);
                echo $this->helper->getPrint($categoryIds);
                echo $this->helper->getPrint($storeId);
                echo $this->helper->getPrint($item);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $this->helper->getPrint($item);
                echo $this->helper->getPrint($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        echo $this->helper->getPrint('Import Complete.');

        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions here solved my problem - so I instead went about it a different way.

I used a CSV method - whereby the user downloads a CSV that was created in a similar fashion to the Export functionality provided by Magento 2. The user can then import that CSV using the import functionality.

The CSV is created using PHP `fputcsv()` function.

To avoid attribute issues (CSV imports don't work unless the attributes and options exist), I made sure they existed while making the CSV. Here is the functions I created for the job:

```
public function createOrGetId($attributeCode, $label) {
    if (strlen($label) < 1) {
        throw new Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Label for %1 must not be empty.', $attributeCode)
        );
    }

    // Does it already exist?
    $optionId = $this->getOptionId($attributeCode, $label);

    if (!$optionId) {
        // If no, add it.

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\OptionLabel $optionLabel */
        $optionLabel = $this->optionLabelFactory->create();
        $optionLabel->setStoreId(0);
        $optionLabel->setLabel($label);

        $option = $this->optionFactory->create();
        $option->setLabel($optionLabel);
        $option->setStoreLabels([$optionLabel]);
        $option->setSortOrder(0);
        $option->setIsDefault(false);

        $this->attributeOptionManagement->add(
            Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $this->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getAttributeId(),
            $option
        );

        // Get the inserted ID. Should be returned from the installer, but it isn't.
        $optionId = $this->getOptionId($attributeCode, $label, true);
    }

    return $optionId;
}

public function getOptionId($attributeCode, $label, $force = false) {
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
    $attribute = $this->getAttribute($attributeCode);

    // Build option array if necessary
    if ($force === true || !isset($this->attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ])) {
        $this->attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ] = [];

        // We have to generate a new sourceModel instance each time through to prevent it from
        // referencing its _options cache. No other way to get it to pick up newly-added values.

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table $sourceModel */
        $sourceModel = $this->tableFactory->create();
        $sourceModel->setAttribute($attribute);

        foreach ($sourceModel->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $this->attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ][ $option['label'] ] = $option['value'];
        }
    }

    // Return option ID if exists
    if (isset($this->attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ][ $label ])) {
        return $this->attributeValues[ $attribute->getAttributeId() ][ $label ];
    }

    // Return false if does not exist
    return false;
}
```

I still need to figure out how to automate the CSV imports, but at least this method avoids obvious (buggy?) limitations within the module framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar for **Grouped Products**. I have created a **simple product** and linked it with a **Grouped Product**.

You should first load the following classes in your constructor.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\LinkFactory $productLinkFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory
)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->productLinkFactory = $productLinkFactory;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}
```

Then, you should create and save the simple product.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->setSku('TEST_SKU');
$product->setName('TEST_NAME');
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setAttributeSetId(1);
$product->setPrice('10');
try {
    $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

After that you can load your parent product, **grouped** or **configurable**.

```
// Load the parent product
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $parentProduct */
$parentProduct = $this->productRepository->get('PARENT_SKU');
```

Finally, you can create product links as follows:

```
// Association with parent product
$link = $this->productLinkFactory->create()
    ->setSku($parentProduct->getSku())
    ->setLinkedProductSku($product->getSku())
    ->setLinkedProductType($product->getTypeId())
    ->setLinkType('associated');
$productLinks = $parentProduct->getProductLinks();
array_push($productLinks, $link);
$parentProduct->setProductLinks($productLinks);
try {
    $parentProduct = $this->productRepository->save($parentProduct);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

I hope it works, I have not tested it for configurable products.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know how it goes :).

Comment: @hazrpg So, how did it go?

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work :( - the products still aren't linked. Is there anything I'm still doing wrong? I've converted from `$link` to `array_push` into an array before doing setProductLinks, since I thought that would work, but it doesn't. I haven't tried without doing that yet, but I will now.

Answer (score 1):

Code should look like:

```
$product = $productFactory->create(['name'=> 'configurable product', ... ]);
$configurableOption = $optionFactory->create([]);
$linkedProduct = $linkFactory->create([]);
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOption);
$product->getExtensionAttributes()->setConfigurableProductLinks($linkedProduct);
$productRepository->save($product)
```

Please note that the API currently does not generate simple products, they need to be created in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say that simple products need to be created in advance - is the code in my example (found in the question) suitable enough for creating the simple products? E.g. can I create the simple products in a loop then attempt to link them after using your code? Is there anything special I need to include in the simple products? Could you please clarify what you mean.