# Creating configurable product attribute with magento > 2.4

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, magento2.4, create-product

I wrote an extension to import products from an XML-file. It is working (for now), but I am using a ->save() method on the Class `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\AttributeFactory`:

```
$attributeModel = $this->configurableAttributeFactory->create();            
$attributes = [$attributeId];
foreach ($attributes as $key => $attributeId) {
    $data = ['attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $key];
    $attributeModel->setData($data);
    $attributeModel->save(); /* <<< deprecated method */
}
```

The save() method seems to be deprecated, and I want to update the extension. So, what is the proper alternative? I already changed the saving-method for the products, to use the resource Model, but I dont know, how to change it for the configurable attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, it took me quite some testing, but to save the attribute, you need to use the class `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute`

I use

```
$this->configurableAttribute = Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute
```

so the resulting code would be:

```
$attributeModel = $this->configurableAttributeFactory->create();            
$attributes = [$attributeId];
foreach ($attributes as $key => $attributeId) {
    $data = ['attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $key];
    $attributeModel->setData($data);
    $this->configurableAttribute->save($attributeModel);
}
```