# How to programmatically assign simple product to configurable on Magento 2.4

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, simple-product

How do you programmatically assign simple product to configurable?
What I tried:

```
$configurableProduct = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
    $configurableProduct->setUsedProductAttributes($product, array($product_jsa_type_attribute_id));
    $product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(4);
    $product->setAssociatedProductIds(array(
       $productObj->getIdBySku($ticketProduct['product_id']),
       $productObj->getIdBySku($couponProduct['product_id']),
    ));
```

Comment: You can check the already mentioned answers in the below reference post. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83107/programmatically-create-a-configurable-product-and-assign-the-simple-product-to

Comment: Does not work for magento 2.4

Comment: is simple product already created ?

Comment: yeah it is already created

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try,

```
$productId = 12; // Configurable Product Id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Load Configurable Product
$attributeModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute');
$position = 0;
$attributes = array(134, 135); // Super Attribute Ids Used To Create Configurable Product
$associatedProductIds = array(2,4,5,6); //Product Ids Of Associated Products
foreach ($attributes as $attributeId) {
    $data = array('attribute_id' => $attributeId, 'product_id' => $productId, 'position' => $position);
    $position++;
    $attributeModel->setData($data)->save();
}
$product->setTypeId("configurable"); // Setting Product Type As Configurable
$product->setAffectConfigurableProductAttributes(4);
$objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attributes, $product);
$product->setNewVariationsAttributeSetId(4); // Setting Attribute Set Id
$product->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);// Setting Associated Products
$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check below link.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315297/85907

In here fully explanation of how to assign simple products to configurable product and explain example with **`color and size`**. So you can understand better what is method magento follow.

If any query let me know will help you.

**`Thanks.`**